# Fn-l puts computer to sleep

Tags: keyboard, suspend, bluetooth, 18.10, logitech

If I hold the Fn button and "l" key, the computer goes to sleep.

Where is this behavior defined?

I'm on a stationary computer, using Ubuntu 18.10

I'm using a Logitech K380 bluetooth keyboard

Comment: What type of keyboard are you using?  As far as I know there is no way to define the `Fn` key combos within the OS itself.

Comment: I'm using a Logitech K380 Bluetooth keyboard

Comment: I only use `Fn` modifier key in conjunction with one of the function keys (`F1` through `F12`). Out of curiousity what were you expecting `Fn`+`I` to perform?

Comment: Well, I am trying to hit Ctrl-l, the Chrome shortcut to highlight the address bar;) It's just that sometimes I miss and then the whole computer goes to sleep. Quite annoying;)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same keyboard and this was driving me nuts for exactly the same reason.
Anyway, the fix [in this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/8nq9c5/disable_xf86sleep_default_action/dzxmmnk/) solved it for me.

By editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and setting `HandleSuspendKey=ignore`, I'm able to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination without anything happening.

Comment: Tried that (with a log off), but didn't work for me. I'm using Logitech wireless keyboard k380.. (Have yet to do a full shutdown)